# Compare data from query result to different table data in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sql-order-by, left-join

**STEP 1**

```
Select data1,name,phone,address from dummyTable limit 4;
```

From above query, I will get the following result for example:

```
 data1 | name | phone | address

 fgh   | hjk  | 567...| CA 
 ghjkk | jkjii| 555...| NY
```

Now, after having the above result I am suppose to match `data1` records that I got from above query to existing another table in a database called `existingTable` which has a same column called `data1` in it. If the result above gives `data1` value as 'fgh' so I take that 'fgh' and compare with that `existingtable` column called `data1`.

**STEP 2**

Next, after I am finished comparing, I need to apply some condition as follows:

```
if((results.data1.value).equals(existingTable.data1.value))
then count --
else
count++
```

So by above condition I am trying to explain, that if the value I got from the result is matched then I do count decrement by 1 and if not then count is incremented by 1.

**Summary**
I basically wanted to achieve this in one single query, is it possible using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Are you trying to compare strings with `==`? You should use `.equals` method.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad,Updated! that is just to give an idea what I am trying to achieve not the real code

Answer (score 0):

I think you can translate that to a simple query:

```
SELECT d.data1, d.name, d.phone, d.address
     , count(*) - 2 * count(e.data1)
FROM  (
   SELECT data1, name, phone, address
   FROM   dummytable
   -- ORDER BY ???
   LIMIT  4
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN existingtable e USING (data1)
GROUP  BY d.data1, d.name, d.phone, d.address;
```

The major ingredient is the [**`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN). Follow the link to the manual.

`count(*)` counts all rows from `dummytable`.
`count(e.data1)` only counts rows from `existingtable` where a matching `data1` exists (`count()` does not count NULL  values). I  subtract that *twice* to match your formula.

About `ORDER BY`: There is no natural order in a database table. You need to order by something to get predictable results.

If there can be **duplicates** in `existingtable` but you want to count every distinct `data1` only *once*, eliminate dupes before you join *or* use an `EXISTS` semi-join:

```
SELECT data1, name, phone, address
      , count(*) - 2 * count(EXISTS (
                          SELECT 1 FROM existingtable e
                          WHERE  e.data1 = d.data1) OR NULL)
FROM  (
   SELECT data1, name, phone, address
   FROM   dummytable
   -- ORDER BY ???
   LIMIT  4
   ) d
GROUP BY data1, name, phone, address;
```

The last count works because `(TRUE OR NULL) IS TRUE`, but `(FALSE OR NULL) IS NULL`.